# Explanation Needed: $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}) = (a-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Simplify: $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

If I just multiply them both as we normally do I get $(a+b+2\sqrt ab)$. But in my books solution sheet, the answer is given as $(a-b)$. Can someone kindly help me on this?

Comment: Are you sure that both factors are the same? Or maybe one of them is $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$?

Comment: It should be $(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)(\sqrt a\color{red}{-}\sqrt b)$. Most likely a typo (either of you or in the book).

Comment: Probably a typo in the book; should be $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=a-b$. (Difference of two squares, $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$.)

Comment: A typo ig. I got super confused. Still thanks y'all.

Answer (score 7):

This is, no doubt, a typo. $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=a-b$. Your computation is correct, in that $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2\ne a-b$.